# How do I find if there's a second element exists with the same name with selenium using XPath?

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I already know the Text of an element in the table:

```
string title1 = Driver.FindElement(
  By.XPath(
    ".//[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl02_TitleLabel']"
  )).Text;
```

How do I verify if there's a second element in the table that has the same text as title1?

Here is my Table structure:

```
<tr class="alt" style="background-color:White;height:110px;">
  <td>
     <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_WindowStartLabel" tabindex="1">
        01/13/2013
     </span>
  </td>
  <td>
     <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_ShowLabel" tabindex="1">
       Lea‌​der of the Pack
     </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_TitleLabel">
       Love at First Bite
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
     <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_PremiereLabel">
        01/12/2013 22:00
     </span>
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Table structure:
<tr class="alt" style="background-color:White;height:110px;">
<td>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_WindowStartLabel"    tabindex="1">01/13/2013</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_ShowLabel"tabindex="1">Leader of the Pack</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_TitleLabel">Love at First Bite</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BreakdownGridView_ctl03_PremiereLabel">01/12/2013 22:00</span>
</td>
...
</tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting title1 try implement logic something like below to find how many elements are there with the same text

```
int count=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='urTable']//*[text()='"+title1+"']")).size();
```

Based on the count it is easy to find how many elements are there with same text.

Answer (score 0):

In your table structure, doing an xpath query as below would select all the *span* tags.

```
//tr/td/span
```

Now, xpath can be used to select the *span* tags with specific text as follows:

```
//tr/td/span[text() = "Text you're matching against"]

/* in your case*/

//tr/td/span[text() = title1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to get spans consist that text....(partial match)

```
int count= driver.FindElements(
  By.XPath(
    ".//span[contains(text(),'"+titleOneText+"')]"
  )).size();
```

This is to get spans text is same....(full match)

```
int count= driver.FindElements(
  By.XPath(
    ".//span[text()='"+titleOneText+"']"
  )).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question if same xpath value having 2 elements. Just see the static value of particular element and take as xpath. it will work definitely. for example

save & cancel button having same xpath value

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='id_sav']")-save
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='id_sav']")-cancel
```

here we can use static element value

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='save']")-save
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='cancel']")-cancel
```